# Склонение процентов

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно произнести «2,9% от суммы»?

*Два целых девять* или *две целых девять десятых процента*?

Answer (score 3):

Второй вариант прочтения (две целых девять десятых процента) - формальный. Он практически обязателен для отвлечённых чисел (без физической размерности) и формальных случаев устной речи (технический доклад, статистический отчёт).

Для повседневной же разговорной формы характерно менее формальное *два и девять (десятых) процента*, где *два* согласовано по роду не с "целыми частями (числа)" (их даже не подразумевают), а с "процентом" (сокращение от "два процента и девять десятых долей его). Аналогично, специалисты в рабочей ситуации *никогда* не скажут о номинале резистора "пять *целых* шесть десятых килоома" (обычный вариант: "пять и шесть килоом").

Answer (score 2):

Второй вариант

> Две целых девять десятых процента от суммы

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант: Две целые девять десятых процента